# Looping through files using dynamic name variable in R

Tags: r, data.table, read.table

I have a large number of files to import which are all saved as zip files.

From reading other posts it seems I need to pass the zip file name and then the name of the file I want to open.  Since I have a lot of them I thought I could loop through all the files and import them one by one.

Is there a way to pass the name dynamically or is there an easier way to do this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
Temp_Data <- NULL
Master_Data <- NULL


file.names <- c("f1.zip", "f2.zip", "f3.zip", "f4.zip", "f5.zip")

for (i in 1:length(file.names)) {
    zipFile <- file.names[i]
    dataFile <- sub(".zip", ".csv", zipFile)

    Temp_Data <- read.table(unz(zipFile, 
                            dataFile), sep = ",")

    Master_Data <- rbind(Master_Data, Temp_Data)

}
```

I get the following error:

```
In open.connection(file, "rt") :
```

I can import them manually using:

```
dt <- read.table(unz("D:/f1.zip", "f1.csv"), sep = ",")
```

I can create the sting dynamically but it feels long winded - and doesn't work when I wrap it with read.table(unz(...)). It seems it can't find the file name and so throws an error

```
cat(paste(toString(shQuote(paste("D:/",zipFile, sep = ""))),",",
      toString(shQuote(dataFile)), sep = ""), "\n")
```

But if I then print this to the console I get:

```
"D:/f1.zip","f1.csv"
```

I can then paste this into `read.table(unz(....)) and it works so I feel like I am close

I've tagged in data.table since this is what I almost always use so if it can be done with 'fread' that would be great.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: The one example in `?fread` uses `system("bunzip2 2008.csv.bz2")` to unzip a file before reading it in. Perhaps you should add a similar line. I'd suggest doing this in a separate loop, though so you can comment it out and avoid repeatedly unzipping the same files.

Comment: What is the full error message and the traceback? Could it be a problem with your working directory or the path to the file?

Comment: @Christoph you are right, it was a problem with my wd, I am using a pen drive to read from - how foolish of me not to check the basics! Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `list.files` command here:

first set your working directory, where all your files are stored there:

```
setwd("C:/Users/...")
```

then

```
file.names = list.files(pattern = "*.zip", recursive = F)
```

then your for loop will be:

```
for (i in 1:length(file.names)) {
#open the files

zipFile <- file.names[i]
dataFile <- sub(".zip", ".csv", zipFile)

Temp_Data <- read.table(unz(zipFile, 
                        dataFile), sep = ",")
# your function for the opened file
Master_Data <- rbind(Master_Data, Temp_Data)

#write the file finaly
write_delim(x = Master_Data, path = paste(file.names[[i]]), delim = "\t", 
col_names = T )}
```

Comment: I have all the filenames, I listed them just as an example. I want to pass the file names to the 'unz' function within my loop so I can open them all recursively.

Comment: you finally will have a Master_Data for each of your zip files. then you need to write it to disk with the unique name of each file. do you want this? please see my answer again. I already edited.

Comment: Thanks, thats pretty much what I had but it turns out there was a problem with the pen drive I was using, apologies for wasting your time but thanks for the reply.